# Making image Re-appear when scrolling back to the top of page

Tags: javascript

I have been given the code:

```
$(function() {
    var $img = $('#arrow');
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        $img.hide();
    });
});
```

This allows me to make an image disappear when I start scrolling but now I want the image to re-appear when the scroll bar gets back to the top of the page.

What's the best way to do this?

I tried:

```
$(function() {
    var $img = $('#arrow');
    $(document).on('top', function() {
        $img.show();
    });
});
```

but I got nothing :(

Comment: Use $(window).on('scroll'... event, and check the scroll height, should be easy to achieve.

Comment: You can use `window.onScroll` to detect the movement of the scrollbar and then use `window.pageYOffset` to get the position of the scrollbar. `window.pageYOffset` will equal to zero if at top. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll

Comment: Harsh down vote, but whatever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the current scroll position:

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/W6nax/**

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('b').text('TOP!');
    }
    else {
        $('b').text($(this).scrollTop());
    }
});
```

The key is the value returned by:

```
$(this).scrollTop()
```

This gives us the current scroll position of the document!

Comment: How would I apply this to my image? I don't know anything about JS just CSS and HTML

Comment: Where I have referenced `$('b')` you need to put `$img` and then swap the `.text()` functions to `.show()` and `.hide()` respectively.

Comment: Fantastic, I just about figured out what to change! I need to learn the basics of JavaScript.. Much appreciated @gvee

Comment: Just noticed that this works perfectly in Chrome and FF but not in IE, is there a variant of the code that would allow it to work in IE?

Comment: I think I am using IE10

Comment: The scroll down. When I start scrolling down it doesn't disappear like on Chrome and FF, the image just stays there

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle to illustrate? Need *something* to debug :P

Comment: It's ok I fixed it. I changed $(document).on to $(window).on